# How to get only integer part from String variable?

Tags: java

I have some string type data in my database table like as `D-101` and `D-102`.
I want to get automatically next data in front end (a JSF web application)  to send to database which  is `D-103`.

For this I want to get only int data from string.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show your actual view code that print theses values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final Pattern lastIntPattern = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]+([0-9]+)$");
            String input = D101;
            Matcher matcher = lastIntPattern.matcher(input);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String someNumberStr = matcher.group(1);
                int lastNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(someNumberStr);
                System.out.println("Test int output - " + lastNumberInt);
                inputList.add(lastNumberInt);
            }
```

then compare max value

```
int currentBranchCode = 0;
        for (Integer CCS : companyArrayList) {
            if (currentBranchCode <= CCS) {
                currentBranchCode = CCS;
            }
        }
```

and then

```
currentBranchCode =currentBranchCode +1;
String codegenerate="D"+currentBranchCode;
```

you must try it.

Answer (score 3):

In your managed bean you can use `split()` function.

```
String s = "D-101";
String[] arr = s.split("[^\\d]+");
System.out.println(arr[1]); //prints 101
```

OR

In the xhtml page you can write an EL like this. Note that **myBean** is the name of your bean and **getColumnValue()** method returns a value of a column(i.e. "D-101").

```
#{myBean.columnValue.split('[^\\d]+')[1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in just a couple of lines:

```
int i = Intger.parseInt(input.replaceAll(".*(?<!\\d)(\\d+)", "$1");
String next = input.replaceAll("(.*)(?<!\\d)\\d+", "$1"+ ++i);
```